# RxJava Completable behavior of Comletable.create{}

Tags: android, rx-java

We were doing a code review and we came to this code:

```
fun saveId(id: Int): Completable {
    return Completable.defer {
        preferencesHelper.saveId(id)
        Completable.complete()
    }
}
```

My colleague argued that it should be changed to:

```
fun saveId(id: Int): Completable {
    return Completable.defer {
        Completable.create { emitter ->
            try {
                preferencesHelper.saveId(id)
                emitter.onComplete()
            } catch (t: Throwable) {
                emitter.onError(t)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And we need help in clearing if these two methods are the same in terms of asynchronous execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are practically the same, but unnecessarily verbose. They can be simplified by using [`fromAction`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Completable.html#fromAction-io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Action-)

```kotlin
fun saveId(id: Int): Completable {
    return Completable.fromAction {
        preferencesHelper.saveId(id)
    }
}
```